# serializer is ignoring a property: value

Tags: c#, serialization

The C# serializer is ignoring a specific property: **value**. Inside this class are two properties. the **valueSpecified** gets serialized. The **value** does not. If I set a breakpoint (>>>) during serialization, the line is never invoked. If I change the property name to Value or valueX then Serialization occurs and the breakpoint is invoked. 
I am stuck with the name because the class is generated from a schema I do not control. is this a bug in the serializer or is value a special word in C#. I tried naming it @value, no joy.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public bool value {
    get {
>>>        return this.valueField;
    }
    set {
        this.valueField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool valueSpecified {
    get {
        return this.valueFieldSpecified;
    }
    set {
        this.valueFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Value' as the property name but pass "value" to the constructor to XmlAttributeAttribute

Comment: I would rather not change the class structure. I want it to conform the schema as much as possible. I am really trying to understand the problem. It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer first looks at `valueSpecified` to see if `value` has been explicitly set or if it is to be considered a default.

If `valueSpecified == true`, the serializer will get the value of `value` and serialise it. 
If it doesn't, the serializer will assume the value is a default and not explicitly serialise it.

Try setting `valueSpecified` to true.